# how to use shared element transition from fragment recycler to Activity

Tags: shared-element-transition

my question is about how to use shared element transition from fragment recycler to Activity.In my it is the major requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SimpleActivityA.this, SimpleActivityB.class);  
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.  
                       makeSceneTransitionAnimation(SimpleActivityA.this,
                            imageView,
                            ViewCompat.getTransitionName(imageView));
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

Comment: i am using your ans then work transition but in and out from device right side and i want like zoom, so what i make changes?